# dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 not returning correct date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, unix-timestamp, nstimeinterval

I have the following method below that is meant to retrieve and convert a unixTimeStamp from an API call to a NSDate object that I can easily manipulate and use. For some reason, this returns wrong values. An example would be when the unixTimeStamp is 1385152832, the date SHOULD be

Fri, 22 Nov 2013 20:40:31 GMT
November 22, 2013 at 3:40:31 PM EST

but instead spits out: 45852-09-07 08:13:52 EST. Does anyone know why this would happen?

```
-(NSDate *)messageDate
{
    NSTimeInterval unixTimeStamp = [[self messageDateString] doubleValue];
    NSDate *messageDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTimeStamp];
    NSAssert(messageDate, @"messageDate should not be nil");
    return messageDate;
}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you formatting the NSDate?  It would not display in the manner you show above.

Comment: It sounds like your `unixTimeStamp` is not set to what you think it is. When I write `NSLog(@"Date: %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1385152832]);` I get `Date: 2013-11-22 20:40:32 +0000`.

Comment: I believe you may need to use an NSDateFormatter to get a proper string representation of an NSDate object. See this [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) for an example.

Comment: I do use an NSDateFormatter to get a proper string representation later on. The numbers I am providing are directly via po'ing the current values from the terminal and such via breakpoint when the method shown above is ran. They are the exact values that are stored.

Comment: I've updated the above with an image.

Comment: po ing the values outputs the same variables as stated above. These are the correct variables.

Comment: Yeah, in general (apparently not the problem in this case) don't trust values displayed in the debugger values window -- they're usually right but not always.  Instead, in the "console" window, type `po messageDate`, eg.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `messageDateString` method is returning **milliseconds** since the epoch, not seconds since the epoch.  Look at the value of `unixTimeStamp` in your debugger pane.  It's 1384803782032.  That is about 1000 times too large to be a current Unix timestamp.

An `NSTimeInterval` is measured in seconds, not milliseconds.  Try this instead:

```
-(NSDate *)messageDate {
    NSTimeInterval unixTimeStamp = [[self messageDateString] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
    NSDate *messageDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTimeStamp];
    NSAssert(messageDate, @"messageDate should not be nil");
    return messageDate;
}
```